# linux + resize2fs with Operation not permitted error

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, disk

I am trying to increase the **/opt** to 65g

but I get the following message

**Operation not permitted While trying to add group #8256**

what is the resolution for that?

```
 root@linux:/opt # lvresize -L 65g /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt
  Extending logical volume opt to 65.00 GiB
  Logical volume opt successfully resized

 root@linux:/opt # resize2fs /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt
  resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
  Filesystem at /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt is mounted on /opt; on-line resizing   required
  old desc_blocks = 240, new_desc_blocks = 260
  Performing an on-line resize of /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt to 68157440 (1k) blocks.
  resize2fs: Operation not permitted While trying to add group #8256
```

Comment: Check your kernel log. Most likely it details the error.

Comment: Not see any relevant info from /var/log/message log

Comment: try this article - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/88483

Comment: What's the output of `dumpe2fs /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt | egrep "(Journal size|Reserved GDT blocks)"` ?